# Add SQL restriction to predicates in JPA query

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have to filter entities according to some parameters sent by client. For this purpose, i create a list of predicates like this:

```
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
                if (filters != null && StringUtils.hasText(filters.getName())) {
                    predicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("name")),
                            "%" + filters.getName().trim().toUpperCase() + "%"));
                } 
  //OTHER FILTERS
```

Now the problem is to add a criteria that is sql syntax. In particular i have to find entities that are located into a particular polygon. So i should add a restriction like this:

```
and within(point, :bounds) = true //bounds is the geometry drawn by client
```

I have read that i could use @Formula to define an sql filter but this annotation works everytime even if filter in input(about localization) is not setted.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call database functions using `CriteriaBuilder.function(...)`. Try `cb.equal(cb.function("within", Boolean.class, root.get("point"), bounds), cb.literal(true))`.

This may or may not work out of the box depending on the type of the `bounds` parameter, because Hibernate needs to recognize it to know its SQL representation, though. You might need to create a custom [`LiteralType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/LiteralType.html)